# How can I download a file from node js router.post?

Tags: node.js, flutter

I want to download a file from router.post method of node.js server in my flutter app

here is my node.js code

```
`var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
var fs = require('fs');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/criar', function(req, res, next) {
    var doc = new PDFDocument();
    doc.pipe(res);

    doc.font('fonts/UbuntuMono-R.ttf')
        .fontSize(25)
        .text('Some text with an embedded font!', 100, 100);

    doc.end();

});

module.exports = router;`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  `res.sendFile();` function to send a file in your response.
Here is an example: `res.sendFile(__dirname + "/foo.pdf")`